Arnold's Darboux's theorem Definition: is coordinate $z$ one-dimensional?
From Arnold's Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics, page 362:

Unlike $x$ and $y$ which are explicitly defined as being tuples, no such definition is given for $z$. Is $z$ written out as $z = (z_1 , \dots , z_n)$ and Arnold simply neglected to write the tuple out, or is $z$ one or even zero-dimensional?

The coordinates are $(x_1,\dots, x_n,y_1,\dots, y_n,z)$ for a total of $(2n+1)$-many coordinate functions (on the $(2n+1)$-dimensional manifold). The function $z$ maps into $\Bbb{R}$ only. So, he means $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i,dy_i+ dz$.

@peek-a-boo Thanks, I missed that implicit part of the problem statement.
